# Splash_Screen to Login_Screen... Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-animation

lib/splash_screen.dart:22:59: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Login_Screen()));
^
lib/login.dart:6:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const Login_Screen(this.show, {super.key});
^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'E:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I've tried my best and can't figure out where I'm going wrong, here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:a_3/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:a_3/login.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive);
  Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Login_Screen()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold (
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.pink],
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft)),
        child: const Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Splash Screen',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 35),
            )
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Login_Screen(this.show, {super.key})`
your constructor for `Login_Screen` required `show` which you did not pass in
`MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Login_Screen()));`

depending on your variable type do this:-
`MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Login_Screen(show)));`

replace `show` with you value here.